# Transfer holdings to different broker w/o paying capital gains?

Tags: united-states, investing, capital-gains-tax, broker

Suppose you own a bunch of stocks/ETFs with a broker (e.g, Fidelity) and you want to switch to another broker (e.g., Vanguard).

You can certainly sell the stocks/ETFs, move the cash to Vanguard, and then rebuy the same stocks/ETFs, but you would incur capital gains tax.

It is possible to move the stocks/ETFs to a different broker without selling them to avoid capital gains tax?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Brokerages should allow moving in assets from other accounts and have specific forms for that. In this case you don't need to liquidate and repurchase, your portfolio will move as is into the new brokerage. You initiate it through the receiving brokerage. [Here's the link](https://investor.vanguard.com/investor-resources-education/education/how-to-transfer-money) to the Vanguard's page on this.

Comment: And for transfers _in the US_ (which Q tagged but didn't explicitly state) this is done via [ACATS](https://www.finra.org/investors/learn-to-invest/brokerage-accounts/understanding-brokerage-account-transfer-process) and [includes basis/holding information at least for lots bought after ~2012-2015](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/62355/when-you-transfer-stock-from-one-broker-to-another-is-cost-basis-sent-to-the-ne)